# Validation Rule - If field isn't 15 characters long OR is updated to blank

Tags: validation-rule

I'm trying to create a simple validation rule that checks the following

- If a value is entered, make sure it's 15 characters long
- If a value is deleted or made blank, let them save the record

Not sure where its going wrong. Here's the formula

```
OR (
ISCHANGED( field ) && LEN( field ) < 15, 
ISCHANGED( field ) && ISBLANK( field ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a validation rule returns `true`, it prevents the record from being saved.

This runs counter to typical developer intuition (it's very easy to try to treat a validation rule like an if/else, mentally).

The better way to frame validation rules is *what needs to happen for us to complain?* In your case, that would be

- If the field has changed
- And the field length is not 15
- And the field is not blank

So using `AND()` instead of `OR()` here, and inverting the blank check is what you want to do. When the field is 15 characters, it doesn't satisfy all 3 conditions. When the field is blank, it doesn't satisfy all 3 conditions.

```
AND(
    ISCHANGED(field),
    NOT(LEN(field) = 15),
    NOT(ISBLANK(field))
)
```

Side note: It's usually a good idea to avoid mixing notation in formulas/validations. Choose to use `AND()` and `OR()`, or `&&` and `||` and stick with it. Otherwise, you're setting yourself up for semantic errors (i.e. things have a higher chance of being evaluated in a way that you didn't intend).